# Replacing a diy'd light fixture

Tags: lighting

[image: while still connected]

The previous homeowner seems to have turned a plug in light into a hard wired one, as pictured above. There was a bare copper wire originating from the box with a cap on it pushed way up and not connected. They also had a bare copper wire from the light fixture simply attached to the ground screw. And the neutral and hot wires were as shown. This light can be turned on/off from 2 switches in the home.

My question is... is it acceptable to follow their lead and connect my light fixture the same way. I have a light fixture that has 3 wires, L, N and unlabeled. Or do I have to fix the ground wire somehow.

Comment: Why do you think this is a DIY fixture it looks professional? Being controlled by 2 switches is even more evediance that it is not DIY in my opinion if properly wired at the time of install. As far as turning a plug in light to a hard wire it depends on how it was done.

Comment: I think maybe it's because that's connected to a lamp?

Comment: Yes that's all I meant. Plus, they had bare copper wire running from the ground screw all the way down the light fixture. As in, not contained in plastic or metal or anyrhing. Not sure if that was safe...?

Comment: ground wires are supposed to be bare and not just for visual identification; if current wants to hop onto them somehow unexpectedly, we shouldn't try to prevent that, we should be glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question. Yes it is acceptable to connect your light fixture the same way. Line to red. White or neutral to white, and ground or bare to ground. Ground wires do not normally carry current unless there is a fault event, and can be run exposed. Best description is that are like an electrical safety valve, they are a secondary source to return a complete a fault back to the over current protection that prevents users from an electrical shock or burn hazard.